# Minimum cost to connect components of a disconnected graph?

Tags: graph-algorithm

We are initially given a fully connected graph by means of an adjacency matrix. Then, some edges are removed such that the graph becomes disconnected and we now have multiple components of this disconnected graph. What is the minimum cost needed to connect all the components?

Comment: You mean the minimum compexity cost in O(n) terms to find a minimal set of edges to add to reconnect all the components? Or in number of edges? You could just pick an existing node at random and connect all other nodes to it that aren't already, which would be O(n) in both algorithm complexity and edges added. I assume you want to do something else?

Comment: Minimum cost in terms of the weights of edges to be added to make it a connected graph again. ( Similar to the concept of finding a minimum spanning tree.)

Comment: So your graph is a weighted graph (i.e., all the edges have weights)?

Comment: Yes, _all_ the edges have weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `G = (V, E_1 ∪ E_2)` be the original (weighted, fully connected) graph and `G' = (V, E_1)` the graph obtained by removing the edges in the set `E_2`.

Consider the graph `G''` that is obtained by contracting the connected components of `G'` (i.e., each connected component becomes a single vertex), where two vertices of `G''` are neighbours if and only if the corresponding connected components in `G'` were connected by an edge in `E_2`. Essentially, this means that the edges of `G''` are the edges in the set `E_2` (the edges that were removed from the original graph).

Observe that adding a subset of the edges from `E_2` to `G'` restores (full) connectivity of `G'` if and only if these edges connect all vertices from `G''`. The cheapest way to do this is by selecting a min-cost spanning tree on `G''` (with respect to the weights of the edges). From your comments, I assume you know what a minimum spanning tree is and how it can be computed.

**One-sentence-summary:**
A cost-minimal set of edges that is needed to restore connectivity can be found by computing a minimum (cost) spanning tree on the graph that is obtained by contracting each of the connected components into a single vertex and that contains, as its edge set, the edges that were removed from the original graph.